# Adding Capability to NFS Server - Compressing/Decompressing Stored/Retrieved Files

Tags: filesystems, nfs

I need to build a custom Suse Linux NFS Server that does compression on certain files that are stored on the disk, and decompresses files as they are read from the disk. This needs to be transparent to the remote users of the file system, meaning that if a user saves a 10MB file named XYZZY.tif on /archiveDirectoryOnNFSServer, that when they do a ls -l on that mounted directory, they will see a 10MB file called XYZZY.tif, even though the actual file stored on the disk on the NFS server will be XYZZY.tif.compressed, and it will be 2MB in size.

I'm expecting that I need to build this as a driver that sits below the NFS Server software stack, but, I'm having difficulty finding where to start. Are there existing NFS Servers that provide this level of customization through APIs? Will I need to modify source of an open source NFS Server, and, if so, is there one that would be easiest to start with, and are they modularly structured such that this will be straight forward? I'm having difficult locating relevant content on the internet, and any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO that kind of functionality is absolutely not the NFS server's responsibility (an nfs server should, well, serve files over nfs), but the underlying filesystem's.  However, there's not that much choice in Linuxland but you could start by checking out [fusecompress](http://code.google.com/p/fusecompress/) and [btrfs](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page).

Answer (score 1):

This post is a bit old so you may already be aware of some options here, but there are a couple others (both for server side).

http://zfsonlinux.org/
zfs filesystem has built-in compression.   I typically use lzjb as it is the fastest compression algorithm and does a reasonable job (MySQL DB's get 2-4x compression, filesystems with non-compressed data get around 4).  you have a choice of algorithm depending on how much CPU time you wish to offer the compression.

if you want different file types compressed then you may consider laying gluster on top of a set of zfs filesystems.
gluster will allow you to store certain file types (by extension) on different underlying filesystems.
in this case, you specify the underlying filesystem as a zfs volume with the particular options you need (for example, .zip and .png go on an uncompressed filesystem,  while things you write once and read many like static html files might go on a higher compression--you'll pay once when it's written but reads should be really fast since it scans fewer disk blocks and decompression is very fast)

zfs will manage the nfs mounts if you use it as your nfs server--you wont want this if you lay gluster on top.

it's easy to specify dynamically other attributes per filesystem (atime/noatime, # of copies if you want redundancy other than your normal raid, you can add SSD's as cache devices to get more performance).

in these solutions, you still send the full uncompressed files over the wire, so it doesn't make up for network performance but gives a lot of options if you're trying to speed up Disk IO or get more utilization out of your drives.